# How to calculate Time between Start and Submit in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How do I calculate time these two blocks Start and Submit?
The Activity column has Start and Submit. I need to calculate the time difference between Submit and the Start before the Submit Activity. How do we calculate that?

Thanks!

Here is the sample Table:

[Sample Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDpUy.png)

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: SQL Server has a bunch of functions related to date/time... I recommend checking them out.

Comment: Take a peek at the window functions lag() or even lead().  In the future, you will get more attention by posting sample data as text and not as an image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took the liberty of converting your image to a usable table:

```
DECLARE @Activity TABLE (Activity VARCHAR(MAX), Timestamp DATETIME)
INSERT @Activity
VALUES
    ('Start', '5/12/21 3:30 PM'),
    ('Start', '5/13/21 3:31 PM'),
    ('Start', '5/14/21 3:33 PM'),
    ('Submit', '5/15/21 3:36 PM'),
    ('Start', '5/14/21 3:37 PM')
```

Without any other identifier to associate the start and submit times, I will assume that the most recent Start applies to a Submit and that other Start entries are ignored. For any given Submit, one way to select a candidate Start is with a CROSS APPLY and appropriate selection, ordering, and TOP 1 criteria.  Something like:

```
SELECT
    StartTime = ST.TimeStamp,
    SubmitTime = SU.TimeStamp,
    Elapsed = SU.TimeStamp - ST.TimeStamp,
    ElapsedMinutes = DATEDIFF(minute,  ST.TimeStamp,  SU.TimeStamp)
FROM @Activity SU
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM @Activity ST
    WHERE ST.Activity = 'Start'
    AND ST.TimeStamp <= SU.TimeStamp
    ORDER BY ST.TimeStamp DESC
) ST
WHERE SU.Activity = 'Submit'
```

Note the last record of your data is the actual closest match using the above criteria, yielding 1439 minutes of elapsed time. If your table contains keys that better associate your start and submit times, you should adjust the above logic accordingly.

I would also recommend an index on TimeStamp for efficient lookup.